# Shared Boundaries too Dark using geom_path()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm working on various mapping of data. One of the maps of interest is taking boundary maps and overlaying them on an exist map. These existing maps may come from Google or other sources.

The issue that I'm having is that when I use geom_path(), with an alpha < 1, if two areas share a boundary, that boundary is darker than other boundaries. Any way to make all the boundaries the same transparency?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(maptools)
library(plyr)

zips <- readShapePoly('cb_2016_us_zcta510_500k.shp')
test <- fortify(zips)
zips@data$id <- rownames(zips@data)
zips.points <- fortify(zips)
zips.df <- join(zips.points, zips@data, by = "id")

test_zips <- c(64002,64012,64013,64014,64015,64029,64030,64034,64050
,64051,64052,64053,64054,64055,64056,64057,64063,64064,64065,64070
,64075,64080,64081,64082,64083,64086,64108,64109,64110,64111,64112
,64113,64114,64121,64123,64124,64125,64126,64127,64128,64129,64130
,64131,64132,64133,64134,64136,64137,64138,64139,64141,64145,64146
,64147,64148,64149,64170,64171,64179,64191,64198,64999,66119,66160
,66205,66206,66207,66208,66209,66211,66222,66224,66251)

Valid_Zips <- zips.df[zips.df$GEOID10 %in% test_zips,]

mapImage <- get_map(location = c(lon = -94.4, lat = 38.9),
color = "color",
source = "google",
maptype = "toner-2011",
zoom = 10)

ggmap(mapImage) + 
geom_path(aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group)
,color="red",data=Valid_Zips,size=1,alpha = .3)
```

[image]

Comment: We need the `Zips` data to make this reproducible

Comment: You may be able to do this by removing duplicates, but it's hard to know without seeing `Zips`

Comment: Updated with more of the code. The underlying shape file comes from the US Census.